# How replace specific quotation marks into apostrophes?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string

My AI model generates this string:

```
'{"name": "hammer 1.5"", "brand": "Eurosteel"}'
```

I want to turn it into dict using `json.loads`. But it is not possible because of "hammer 1.5"" in value of name key. So I want to turn my string into this string:

```
'{'name': 'hammer 1.5"', 'brand': 'Eurosteel'}'
```

How could I do that? I want to do it with function to be able to apply it to all similar cases.

P.S.
Another option is to add \ before ":

```
'{"name": "hammer 1.5\"", "brand": "Eurosteel"}'
```

Comment: You should try to get your `"AI model"` to either generate proper `json`, or (probably better) to generate the data in a different format. You don't want to be fiddling with quotes, because a corner case will eventually show up that you can't handle.

Comment: @quamrana well it is easier to make post-processing of generated result than endlessly experiment with prompts and hope for the best. ai models are unpredictable. one prompt can work well for certain example and don't work for another one

Comment: Are you requesting the data in `json` format? I would pick a different format.

Comment: @quamrana yes. i also tried yaml, but it didnt seem better. i need results in json format cause i ask model to extract specifications out large amount of data

Comment: *it is easier to make post-processing* -- You are wrong.  The processor that is generating this material is BROKEN.  It is generating invalid data.  Who knows what the next screw-up might be?  The RIGHT engineering answer is to fix your generator, not to try to guess what garbage it might produce next.

Comment: Repeat the parsing-reprompt loop until it gives you something that you are satisfied with. Sounds easier than fixing broken JSON and prompt engineering, no?

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I want to turn it into dict ...*
>
> *... I want to do it with function to be able to apply it to all similar cases. ..."*

Use a *regular expression* to capture the values.

As a note, if the value contains a `",` or `"}`, this pattern will fail.

```
"(.+?)": "(.+?)"[,}]
```

Here is an example

```py
import re
s = '{"name": "hammer 1.5"", "brand": "Eurosteel"}'
d = dict(re.findall('"(.+?)": "(.+?)"[,}]', s))
```

Output

```
{'name': 'hammer 1.5"', 'brand': 'Eurosteel'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use json.dumps to make the conversion of the data into a dictionary and apply the correct quotes around keys and values:

```
import json
data = '{"name": "hammer 1.5", "brand": "Eurosteel"}'
dct = json.loads(data)
```